# ASP.NET Core 2.1 How to determine Claims without Authorize Attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I'm building a web application which uses the cookie authentication built into ASP.NET Core 2.1.

I have my own sign in method which queries my own custom password verification and setting of claims. Roughly it looks like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<LoginResponse>> DoLogin([FromBody] LoginRequest req)
{
    // fetch account and verify password

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, account.AccountId.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, account.EmailAddress, ClaimValueTypes.Email),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "member", ClaimValueTypes.String)
    };

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "password");
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

    return new LoginResponse
    {
        Success = true
    };
}
```

I would like to conditionally render a "Log Out" button on various parts of the site if the user has the cookie which authenticates the user. Additionally I'd like to fetch the Sid claim so I can deliver personalized messaging on some public parts of the site.

The problem I have is that the way I have been fetching the Sid only works if my controller or controller action has an `[Authorize]` attribute on it. Without the `[Authorize]` attribute, the claim is missing.

Code:

```
public static int? GetNullableAccountId(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    var claim = principal.FindFirst((Claim c) => { return c.Type == ClaimTypes.Sid; });

    if (claim == null)
        return null;

    return int.Parse(claim.Value);
}

// then in the controller I try to get the account id:
var accountId = accessor.HttpContext.User.GetNullableAccountId();
// always null even when I have a valid cookie
```

I swear that I didn't need the `[Authorize]` attribute for this to work in prior versions of ASP.NET Core, but I couldn't find anything meaningful in change logs.

Is there some trick to getting ASP.NET Core to build the user identity on all calls or am I taking the wrong approach all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it was a silly mistake. I was invoking `app.UseAuthentication()` after `app.UseMvc()` when configuring my application builder.

The documentation actually explicitly states the following:

> Call the UseAuthentication method before calling UseMvcWithDefaultRoute or UseMvc

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configuration

Comment: I was stuck on this for so long. I have to save this for posterity.